# Inequalities in proof of Bernstein-type lemmas

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm working through the proof of Lemma 2.1 in Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin's *Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear PDE*. The place where I'm stuck boils down to (I think) proving the following inequality:
$$\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb R^d)}\leq\||\cdot|^{2d}f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)}$$
where we have that $f$ is not compactly supported. I think I've proved that there is some $n$ such that $\|f\|_{L^1}\leq\||\cdot|^nf\|_{L^\infty}$, but not the stronger result that $n=2d$ works. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired inequality is false, even with constants, since it does not have the right sort of homogeneity. Take a function $f$ for which the inequality does hold, and define

$$g_{\lambda}(x) = \lambda^{d} f(\lambda x)$$

This is the $L^1$ dilation of $f$, and $$\|g_{\lambda} \|_1 = \|f\|_1$$ for all $\lambda > 0$. On the other hand,

\begin{align*}
\big| |x|^{2d} g_{\lambda}(x) \big| = \lambda^{-d} \big| |\lambda x|^{2d} f(\lambda x)\big| = \lambda^{-d} |y|^{2d} |f(y)|
\end{align*}
It follows that 
$$\big\| |.|^{2d} g_{\lambda} \big\| = \lambda^{-d} \big\||.|^{2d} f\big\|$$
But then we have
$$\|g_{\lambda}\|_1 = \|f\|_1 \le \big\||.|^{2d} f\big\|_{\infty} = \lambda^d \big\||.|^{2d} g_{\lambda}\big\|_{\infty}$$
Now send $\lambda$ to zero to find a counterexample.

Comment: If $\lambda=0$ isn't $g_\lambda=0$? I happen to know that $f$ is not compactly supported so I'm not sure this is a contradiction.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter Here $\lambda > 0$ - by "send $\lambda$ to zero" I mean taking $\lambda$ small enough to make the right hand side of the inequality so small that there is a contradiction, not actually letting $\lambda = 0$. Note also that $f$ has (non-)compact support if and only if $g_{\lambda}$ does.

Comment: Oops read that as "set $\lambda$"

Comment: You're right this is wrong.

Comment: Although it's not clear to me why the above is a counterexample--perhaps $\|g_\lambda\|_1$ goes to zero faster than the right-hand side as $\lambda\to0$.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter $\|g_{\lambda}\|_1$ is *constant* in $\lambda$ by choosing $g_{\lambda}$ to be the correctly scaled dilation of $f$.

Comment: Oh that's right. But the right-hand side is also constant in $\lambda$?

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter No, the right side is not constant in $\lambda$. It's exactly equal to $\lambda^d C$ where $C$ is the fixed number given by $$C = \big\||.|^{2d} f\big\|_{\infty}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33452/discussion-between-stan-corey-carter-and-user).

Answer (score 3):

The inequality you are trying to prove is indeed false, but the following is true : A positive constant C exists for which

$∥f∥_{L^1(R^d)}≤ C ∥ (1 + |⋅|^{2})^d f∥_{L^∞((R^d))}$

And it comes from the fact that the function $\frac{1}{(1 + |⋅|^{2})^d}$ is integrable, thus one may write :

$∥f∥_{L^1(R^d)} =  ∥(1 + |⋅|^{2})^df \frac{1}{(1 + |⋅|^{2})^d}∥ _{L^1((R^d))}$

And the results comes from the application of Hölder inequality with p=1 and q = $\infty$

I think this is the argument that is intended in Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin's book.